# Show that any transitive class is contained in $WF$

Tags: set-theory

I need an help with this exercise. It states: Work in $ZF^-$. Let C a transitive class. Show that if $\in$ is well-founded on $C$, then $C\subseteq WF$.
I thought to argue by contradiction: let $x\in C$ such that $C\notin WF$. Then there exists $y\in x$ such that $y\notin WF$, so the set $D=\{y\in x: y\notin WF\}$ is nonempty. By well-foundedness, $D$  has $\in$-minimal element, namely $y^*$. By transitivity, we have that $y^*\in C$. Since $y^*\notin WF$ ,there exists $z^*\in y^*$ such that $z^*\notin WF$. Now, if I could use axiom of foundation, I would get that also $z^*\in x$, otherwise I would have $z^*\in y^*\in x \in z^*$ which is impossible by foundation, and so I would get a contradiction with the $\in$-minimality of $y^*$. How can I finish the proof without using axiom of foundation?

P.S. $WF$ are the well-founded sets; $WF=\bigcup_{\alpha\in ON}WF(\alpha)$, where $WF(0)=0, WF(\alpha+1)=\mathcal{P}(WF(\alpha)), WF(\alpha)=\bigcup_{\beta\in \alpha} WF(\beta)$ if $lim(\alpha)$.

Comment: Maybe now I see. $\{x,y^*,z^*\}$ is a nonempty subset of $C$, so it must have $\in$-minimal element. But that minimal element isn't $x$ since $y^*\in x$, and it can't be $y^*$, since $z^*\in y^*$. So it has to be $z^*$. In particular $z^*\in x$, then a contradiction with the $\in$-minimality of $y^*$ in $x$. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

If $\in$ is well-founded we can do $\in$-induction on $C$. Show the following,

> If $x\in C$, and for all $y\in x$, $y\in WF$ then $x\in WF$.

(Hint: since $x$ is a set, $x\subseteq WF(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha$.)