# Transitive Class is a subclass of WF

Tags: set-theory

I’m trying to understand Lemma II.4.27 from Kunen’s Set Theory.
The statement is the following.

> **Lemma II.4.27** Suppose that M is a transitive class such that the Comprehension Axiom holds in M, and assume that for every subset $x \subseteq M$, there is a set $y \in M$ such that $x \subseteq y$. Then all the $\text{ZF}$ axioms hold in $M$.

I’m having issues proving the axiom of foundation assuming that we are working in $\text{ZF}^-$ (i.e. without the axiom of foundation).
The proof stated in the book is rather straight forward and uses Lemma II.2.4.

> **Lemma II.2.4** ($\text{ZF}^-$ - P) For any class $M$: 
>  $\dots$ 
>  2. If $M \subseteq WF$, then the Foundation Axiom holds in $M$.

I understand the proof of Lemma II.2.4, but I don’t see how $M \subseteq WF$ in the case of Lemma II.4.27.

I’ve see this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/818229/show-that-any-transitive-class-is-contained-in-wf) but it seems to assume that $\in$ is well-founded, which isn’t the case here.

Comment: You need to assume Foundation to show 4.27: Take any model of ZFC without Foundation (like the model of Aczel's Anti-Foundation axiom), then the model would think $V$ satisfies conditions of Lemma 4.27, but it does not satisfy Foundation.

Comment: Makes total sense, I haven’t seen the Anti-Foundation axiom yet but I’ll surely give it look. Thanks!

Comment: Is that the new Kunen or the old Kunen?

Comment: It’s the 2013 version, I’ve heard that some of the revisions changed a lot but I don’t know if it’s the new or the old one…

Comment: The 2013 version is the new one. The older one was written around the 1980s.